# Getting Extra Space Around My Mobile Page and Background Cuts Off

Tags: css, html, mobile, background-image

I am getting extra space around my mobile page to the right and bottom, I've been working at it for awhile, but can't figure out which element/styling is causing it(view page in Chrome console as iPhone 6 and you'll see what I mean).

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

dev site:
http://rosasfreelancedesign.com/dev/douglas/mobile/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a width to your  tag. Does it really need to be 100% width?

```
<h2>Douglas Arizona</h2>
```

Should be something like:

```
<h2 id="name">Douglas Arizona</h2>
```

And the style should be something like:

```
h2#name {
      width: 200px;
      }
```

Of course, 200px is arbitrary and you can set it to whatever you like or need.

Comment: I am referring the the page as a whole, not the header element

Comment: Have you tried my solution? It will remove the extra space to the right and bottom, as you requested. The H2 is leaking over to the right, well past the full width of the page, causing unnecessary white space. By limit the H2 you will restore the page width back to 100% of screen size, as you want it to be.

Comment: What on earth, it worked, but I am confused as to why 100% will increased the width like that. Do you have a relevant article on the topic?

Comment: Because you were using ``left: 25%;``, the H2 block itself was pushed 25% away from the left edge of the page. As a result, at width 100%, the H2 block was actually hitting 125% from the left edge of the page.